# Machine Learning: Convert array to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use DictVectorizer in sklearn to train categorical features. Some features are integers, some doubles and some strings.

I have an array of data:

```
array([['SalesPerson', 'Customer', 'Createdon', ...,
        'TotEmailsOnFRIPM', 'TotEmailsOnSATPM', 'TotEmailsOnSUNPM'],
       ['Jim Bean',
        'Acme Inc', '30:52.0', ..., '0', '0',
        '0'],
       ['Stephie Graph',
        'BigOil', '47:12.0', ..., '0', '0',
        '0'],
       ..., 
       ['Steven Amos',
        'BBF Industries', '35:41.0', ..., '0', '0',
        '0']])
```

where the first row is the column header, and the rows beneath are the values.

In order to use DictVectorizer I converted this array to a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
features = data[0,:]

dict_list = []
N, F = data.shape
d = {}

for n in range(N):
    for f in range(F):
        feature = features[f]
        d[feature] = data[n,f]

    dict_list.append(d)
```

This produced a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[{'SalesPerson':'Jim Bean', 'Customer':'Acme Inc', 'Createdon':'35:41.0',...,'TotEmailsOnSUNPM':'0'},
...
{'SalesPerson':'Stephen Amos', 'Customer':'BBF Industries', 'Createdon':'30:52.0',...,'TotEmailsOnSUNPM':'0'}]
```

However, when I run DictVectorizer on this I get an array full of 1s.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
v = DictVectorizer()

X_train = v.fit_transform(data_list)

X_train.toarray()
```

Produces:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       ..., 
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Where am I going wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the loop:

```
d = {}
for n in range(N):
    for f in range(F):
        feature = features[f]
        d[feature] = data[n,f]
    dict_list.append(d)
```

where you really intend to do this instead:

```
for n in range(N):
    d = {}
    for f in range(F):
        feature = features[f]
        d[feature] = data[n,f]
    dict_list.append(d)
```

**So why is the result all one?**

As `dict` is mutable, during the loop you have been modifying the same `dict` over and over again. In other words, in the end `dict_list` just holds a bunch of reference to the same `dict`.

Effectively, you have `N` identical samples in the dataset that is to be vectorized. `DictVectorizer` will do a one-hot encoding for your features, and since it only sees a single value for each individual feature, each feature value is encoded with only 1 bit, resulting in the all-1 array as the output.

Comment: Thank you, silly mistake. I have another question now this is working, I have separate columns of different data types (strings, floats and ints) and I want to concatenate them without losing their type. hstack and column stack lose the type and generalise them  all to strings.

Comment: Have you considered using ``DataFrame`` in [``pandas``](http://pandas.pydata.org/)? Otherwise, you probably need something like [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) for such heterogeneous data.